# How to show Loading Indicator in InAppWebView Flutter? (flutter_inappwebview)

Tags: flutter, webview

I want to show Loading first before the web view data is displayed on the screen. How can do that using the [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) package?

This is my code:

```
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        isLoading
            ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : const SizedBox(),
        Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            Expanded(
              child: InAppWebView(
                key: _key,
                onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = false;
                  });
                },
                initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                    url: Uri.parse('https://example.com/')),
                initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                  crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
                  ),
                ),
                androidOnPermissionRequest:
                    (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin,
                        List<String> resources) async {
                  return PermissionRequestResponse(
                    resources: resources,
                    action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Stack` to layout a loading indicator on the top of `InAppWebView`. Then use [onLoadStart](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_inappwebview/latest/flutter_inappwebview/InAppWebView/onLoadStart.html) and [onLoadStop](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_inappwebview/latest/flutter_inappwebview/InAppWebView/onLoadStop.html) to control the visibility of the loading indicator.

Comment: Can you please provide a working code example?

Comment: I have updated my question with the new code. It's still not working. :\

Comment: you're showung SizedBox if isLoading was false

Comment: @HKN that's how it should be...

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @user18309290 answer:

**Make sure that the order of the widgets that appear in your `Stack` is correct**. My second problem was that the `InAppWebView` (which is cover the whole screen), was above my `CircularProgressIndicator` widget. Reordering the `Stack` of widgets solved the issue.

Here is the correct working code:

```
Stack(
      children: [
        isLoading
            ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : const SizedBox(),
        Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            Expanded(
              child: InAppWebView(
                key: _key,
                onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = false;
                  });
                },
                initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                    url: Uri.parse('https://example.com/')),
                initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                  crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
                  ),
                ),
                androidOnPermissionRequest:
                    (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin,
                        List<String> resources) async {
                  return PermissionRequestResponse(
                    resources: resources,
                    action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 6.x, use `Stack` to place a loading indicator at the top of the `InAppWebView`. Then use `onProgressChanged` to control the visibility of the **loading indicator**.

```
   class ExemplePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<ExemplePage> createState() => _ExemplePageState();
    }
    
    class _ExemplePageState extends State<ExemplePage> {
      bool showLoading = true;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Material(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              InAppWebView(
                initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(
                  data: '<html></html>',
                ),
                onProgressChanged: (_, progress) {
                  if (progress >= 100) {
                    setState(() {
                      showLoading = false;
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
              if (showLoading) CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```